# how do you link to a standard domain within Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to create hyperlinks for saved urls in Django, and in my template I had:

```
{% if active_articles %}
    {% for article in active_articles %}
        {{ article.url }}
        <a href="{% article.url %}"><p>{{ article.title }}</p></a>
...etc...
```

but instead of the expected "www.google.com", I received http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/www.google.com. Even more puzzling, if I replace it to:

```
{% if active_articles %}
    {% for article in active_articles %}
        {{ article.url }}
        <a href="www.google.com"><p>{{ article.title }}</p></a>
```

I get the same behavior. I googled absolute/relative url behavior in Django and didn't see the solution, but I'd be surprised if I'm the first person to have this issue.

What is the correct way to directly link to a url on someone else's domain (not within your app)? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems the urls in your database don't have the required `http://` or `https://` prefix which you are missing. You could add `http://` to your template:

`<a href="http://{% article.url %}"><p>{{ article.title }}</p></a>`

Comment: Yep. This isn't even really a django question. django isn't converting the URLs, the browser is. I disagree with adding the http:// in the template, though. What if it's a different protocol? HTTPS? FTP? The model in question should use a [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) for the `url` field, and validate that the URL includes the protocol.